# Unset ignorecase in vim?

Tags: vim

`:set ic` ignores the case. How do you unset this?

Comment: For future reference, this would have give you your answer, :help 'ic'

Answer (score 87, accepted):

:set noic, or :set noignorecase

Really intuitive, right? :)

Comment: In Vi I'm pretty sure you can also use :set noic (which is more intuitive)

Comment: Sure,but even more intuitive, to me anyway, would be :unset ic. I guess I'll keep using vim anyway :)

Comment: Yes, that would be even nicer =)

Comment: ":help set" will tell you all about the :set command, including :set no{command} to unset a boolean, and even :set {command}! which toggles it

Comment: Cool, so you could do :set ic! to toggle it then?

Comment: Yep, :set ic? confirms that :set ic! toggles between "ignorecase" and "noignorecase"

Comment: `set ignorecase!` should work too. Worked with `:set cursorcolumn!` at least

Comment: @DaveRay haha, a wonderfully self-aware comment subtly criticizing perfectionism  :P

Comment: There are cases when the "intuition" part is a bit ackward: `set nohidden`, shouldn't that be `set show`... That worked, btw.

Answer (score 23):

You can also toggle the setting with :set ic! and query its value with :set ic?

Answer (score 18):

prefix searched string with "\C" (without quotes), eg:

```
/\Croot
```

Comment: I think you mean \C. Small c means ignore case.

Answer (score 16):

Pay attention to `'smartcase'` option. It overrides the `'ignorecase'` option if the search pattern contains upper case characters.

i.e. having `'ignorecase'` and `'smartcase'` on `/foo` will find `foo`, `Foo` and `FOO`, but `/Foo` will find only `Foo`, not `foo`.

You can also tell Vim that you want to search case-sensitive despite of `'ignorecase'` setting by using `\C` somewhere in the search pattern. By using `\c` in the search pattern you tell Vim to ignore case while searching, despite of `'ignorecase'` setting.